# how to get data from cache memory without executing mysql db query

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache

In my spring application, i am using mysql query to get values from DB and do processing.This is done for every n minutes with same query . i want to reduce/optimize this using cache mechanism . Is there any way to avoid the second time querying to DB in case there is no change in DB.
Is there any way to do this without changing mysql data base configuration?

Comment: Check the mysql manual for setting the mysql cache http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql has  an  option to cache queries. Take a look at the  mysql manual section:
The MySQL Query Cache

Comment: Is there any way to do this without changing mysql data base configuration?

Comment: I believe the default is to cache it. If you don't use  that then  you can use a trigger on each update or insert. The trigger would insert a date into another table. Then you could read from that. If your app is the only thing making changes then you could track it that way,  but that would not be very safe. Why do you want to cache? Is you query taking a  long time  to return a result?